# Issues using custom testInstrumentationRunner

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, android-testing

I've not found any post on Stack Overflow that helped, so I'm posting my own question.

I have a custom `testInstrumentationRunner` that when set doesn't run any tests.
The logs says:

```
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
Running tests
adb shell am instrument -w -m  --no-window-animation  -e debug false -e class 'com.my.app.MyFragmentTest' com.my.app.debug.test/com.my.app.CustomTestRunner
Connected to process on device
```

When running the normal `androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` the tests run, but fail, because I need the custom runner.

The runner is set up like the androidx one, in:

```
defaultConfig {
// testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
   testInstrumentationRunner "com.my.app.CustomTestRunner"
}
```

It's also located in the `com.my.app` package in `androidTest`-folder

The code for the runner is:

```
package com.my.app

import ...

class CustomTestRunner: AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        DexOpener.install(this)
        Timber.i("This should print hopefully")
        return super.newApplication(cl, ApplicationTest::class.java.canonicalName, context)
    }
}
```

Not sure if it matters, but here's the code for the application class, which extends the application class used for the app itself:

```
package com.my.app

class ApplicationTest: MyApplication() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appContext = applicationContext
        initializeDependencyInjection()
    }

    override fun initializeDependencyInjection() {}
}
```

I have a test-case I'm trying to run, which contains 7 tests. The androidx runner fails on 7/7 tests. But when I run with the custom runner, I get `duration 0ms` and 0/0 tests.

So it seems like Android isn't detecting this runner. I also get the same results using a random name in the testInstrumentationRunner, like `testInstrumentationRunner "not.a.TestRunner"`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've already solved the issue or switched jobs to growing potatoes or something more productive, but I just spent my whole morning debugging this same exact scenario and managed to find a solution:

The custom instrumentation runner you have is not ignored, but there is something broken in your custom Test Application initialization. Probably in your replacement dependency injections, like it was in my case. When you run the tests using the custom runner, the custom Test Application silently crashes immediately, but this is not indicated in the test results or in any other easily visible place. **The crash stack trace is, however, accessible in logcat.** So solve that first, and then try using your custom test runner again.

Answer (score 0):

When testing a library module, you can link the test application in `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:name="com.my.app.ApplicationTest"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I've tried your approach, though the issue remains the same. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Do not mix between Instrumentation Tests and Unit Tests:

**Unit Tests**

Unit tests runs in local JVM and minimizes the execution time.
Unit Tests cannot test UI of the app without mocking activity objects.
Unit test are used for white box testing for testing code.
Most of the time Unit Tests are written by Developers.
You don’t need a device connected for execution of Unit Tests.

**Instrumentation Tests**

Instrumentation tests are used for black box testing.
It is used to test GUI of the application along with its functionality in real environment.
For execution of Instrumentation tests you need a device /emulator on which the application is first installed and then tests are executed.
Automation Testers are involved in writing instrumentation framework.

Comment: I'm not mixing those. My Unit Tests are running just fine, and they're in the "Test" folder. Whilst the issue is with my Instrumentation Tests, located in the "AndroidTest" folder.